# PyCrypto: How much random data is considered secure?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, pycrypto

I'm using the RSA implementation in PyCrypto. With regard to the encrypt(self, plaintext, K) method K is a parameter of random data. I want to know how much random data needs to be passed in order for the encryted data to be considered secure. For example in my implementation I am passing a strong prime number of 1024 bits via the Crypto.Util.number module like so:

```
enc_data = public_key.encrypt(data, number.getPrime(1024))
```

Is this considered 'secure enough'?

Thanks

Comment: @Tom Yes, I'm using Crypto.PublicKey.RSA. In the [docs](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#the-elgamal-and-dsa-algorithms) it talks about using the Crypto.Util.number module to generate a prime number of a suitable length. My question is focusing on what is considered a "suitable" or "secure" length.

Comment: I downloaded the package but now I can't find the source code for that class. I must be losing my mind.

Comment: @Greg are you looking for the number class? it's in Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util

Comment: I don't see why you would need to pass a **prime number** here, if the goal is to have a random number - this would have less entropy than a normal random number of this size (and be harder to create).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSA implementation **does not** use the K parameter. You may ignore it; the RSA implemention does.

Looking at lines 59-60 of `pycrypto-2.3/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py` you see the following:

```
def _encrypt(self, c, K):
    return (self.key._encrypt(c),)
```

Which proves that `K`, if supplied, is ignored.

**Official documentation**

Plus, the developers declare this *explicitly* in the documentation. In fact, if you create a public key `public_key` and you type

```
help(public_key.encrypt)
```

you will obtain their documentation, which explicitly says:

```
encrypt(self, plaintext, K) method of Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj instance
Encrypt a piece of data with RSA.

...
...

:Parameter K: A random parameter (*for compatibility only. This
 value will be ignored*)
:Type K: byte string or long
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for that please?